# Google Play - Enabling pre-registering for my app

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

I have an app I will launch in a month (or so), so I'm thinking about enabling the pre-registration feature of Google Play so that my users would be notified when the app comes live.
But I don't find such an option inside Google Play Developer Console. 
I know there was a similar question here (of May 2015), but then it was only a single game which offered that feature.
Right now there are some apps that offer it, and I wonder if this option exists inside Google Play Developer Console or if instead is something only available to some companies, like big game companies.

Thank you.